# Inflate two layouts with different functionalities

Tags: android, android-layout

I am inflating the same layout twice in my code.
But I want to differentiate between them.

I have to give different function to views for different values of i.
But when I click any View it takes the last inflated View by default.

```
if(i==1||i==3||i==5){
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
                View inflatedLayout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.multipleselect, null, false);
                activity_new.addView(inflatedLayout);
            }
```

Comment: I guess what you need is a ListView or a RecyclerView so that the content of each row depends on the data you pass to it. 
Check this link for ListViews: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html
And this one for RecyclerViews :
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can detect View click and modify it according to your use.

```
for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
                View inflatedLayout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.multipleselect, 
                 null, false);
                 inflatedLayout.setTag(i+"");
                 inflatedLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               Toast.make(view.getContext(),view.getTag().toString(),Toast.SMALL_LENGHT).show();

            }
            });
                activity_new.addView(inflatedLayout);
            }
```

Comment: Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need inflate the same layout twice. Just call the behavior(different functions) you need in some specific case.

Comment: i have 1000 of questions of different type.  all questions layout will vary according to question type. so i have to inflate that layout may b 200 times for one question.

Comment: Can you provide the main idea of what do you want to implement. Maybe you chose wrong way in root?

Comment: Do you want to have diffrent layout but want to write code once in your activity ?

Comment: @Karan instead you should use ListView/RecyclerView with ViewTypes . If you don't know that concept let us know. Also i have given you a answer for you asked. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45455139/1488066

Comment: i m taking a Linear layout as parent. and then in that linear layout i m infalting different type of layout according to question type (either multiple choice or give answer in edit text).

Comment: Inflating the layout each time is not a good idea. I think the better way is to play with visibility of different views, depending of "i". And then the handling of the user's actions also should be related to "i".

Comment: i am creating a survey app so i have to show each question at same time. i cant play with visiblity.